# How to insert into HashMap dereferenced iterator of LinkedList?

Tags: rust

How to fix issue on a screenshot? I already tried to make it mutable, but that is not the point. What can it be, how to get rid of it? I will be thankful for the changes in the code.

screenshot:
[image: scr]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/cczp2QM/Untitled.png))</sub>

```
let mut buf = vec![0 as u8; 4096];
for stream in listener.incoming() {
    match stream {
        Ok(mut stream) => {
            match stream.read(&mut buf) {
                Ok(size) => {
                    //Get List of names
                    let names: LinkedList<String> = serde_json::from_slice(&buf[..size])?;
                    for name in names.iter() {
                        if (*data).available.contains_key(&*name) {
                            //If file already exist just update Vec of IP
                            (*data)
                                .available
                                .get_mut(&*name)
                                .unwrap()
                                .push(stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
                        } else {
                            //In another case - adding file with first IP that share it
                            let mut v: Vec<SocketAddr> = Vec::new();
                            v.push(stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
                            (*data).available.insert(*name, v);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("An error occurred, {}", stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
                }
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error: {}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `into_iter()` instead `iter()` to get ownership of name so you can move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want a `LinkedList` and not a `Vec` as output from your JSON parser? From the [`LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) docs:

> It is almost always better to use `Vec` or `VecDeque` because array-based containers are generally faster, more memory efficient, and make better use of CPU cache.

To solve your problem, you should loop over `names` instead of `names.iter()`. This will make the list unusable after the `for` loop.
You will then have to remove the dereferences in your code, i.e. write `&name` instead of "`&*name`" and `name` instead of `*name`. However, you shouldn't have written `&*name` at all because the `&` and `*` in `&*name` are cancelling each other out.